Seams on baked normal map and inside of object is completly messed up - how to fix, why does it happen?
Baked from a high poly version to the lower poly, 1k texture. Unsure what to do about these issues.
enter image description here


File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RDE3Lpq6YbyM4ixG9jt4d740EKG53WwC/view?usp=sharing
